# Upload video from front end programmatically Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, file, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to upload video from front end programmatically in wordpress page.

This is my code:

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['uploadvideo'])) {

    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {

       require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
       require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
       require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' ); 
     }

      $uploadedfile = $_FILES['photoContent'];
      $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
      $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );


      if ( $movefile )
      {
      $image_url = $movefile["url"];
      $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
      $image_data = file_get_contents($image_url);
      $filename = basename($image_url);
      if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path']))
      $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
      else
      $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
      file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

      $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
      $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
      );

      $listing_post_id = 780 ; // post id
      $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $listing_post_id);

      $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
      wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

      /*end file uploader*/

      }
   }

   ?>
<form method ="post" action="" name="uploadvideo"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label for="ug_photo">Your Video Files
   <input type="file" value="" name="photoContent" id="ug_photo" class="" multiple="multiple"></label>
   <label for="ug_submit_button">
   <input type="submit" value="uploadvideo" name="uploadvideo" id="ug_submit_button" class="btn"></label>
</form>
```

But it is not working. I have hardcoded an post id 780, I will change that later.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by corrupt? Can you please explain what error you are seeing?

Comment: @krishna89 I am not getting any error, Its not uploading. Edited the question.

Comment: turn on error reporting or look at the error log of your webserver. without an actual error message it's next to impossible to guess what the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

1. wp_generate_attachment_metadata() won't work if you do not include this file :-
   require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
2. use wp_upload_bits( $_FILES['picture']['name'], null, @file_get_contents( $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'] ) ); to upload files other than images

Answer (score -1):

Please try changing the line `$uploadedfile = $_FILES['photoContent'];` to `$uploadedfile = $_FILES['ug_photo'];` in your code.

Comment: The name of the file field is `photoContent`, the id is irrelevant, it is not transferred to the server.